# How to count the number of 1's from the total matrix

Tags: matlab

I have  code like below:

```
N=10;
R=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
p=[0.1,0.2,0.01];
B = zeros(N , N);
B(1:N,1:N) = eye(N);
C=[B;R];

for q=p(1:length(p))
    Rp=C;
    for i=1:N
        if(rand < p)
            Rp(i,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

from this code I vary the value of `p`. So for different value of `p`, i am getting different `Rp`. Now I want to get the total number of "1"'s from each `Rp` matrix. it means may be for p1 I am getting Rp1=5, for p2, Rp=4.

For example

```
Rp1=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0],
Rp2=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0],
Rp3=[0 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0],
```

So total result will be 2,3,1.

I want to get this result.

Comment: thought about `sum(Rp)`? as you just have 1's it would be the easiest way to go...

Comment: `sum(Rp(:))` will work since Rp is binary. The `(:)` makes it sum over all the dimensions by first linearizing the matrix

Comment: Yes i know but i need to sum all the 1's together.Like Rp=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0] then my Rp=2.I cannot do this.i need to get all the values Rp values.

Comment: @Dan-if i use your code then it sum up all the 1's from every Rp.But i need to sum the 1's for each Rp individually.

Comment: From your comments I assume you want to store the result of each sum as you loop over the values of p.  ---- Sidenote: You can simplify your for loop from `for q=p(1:length(p))` to `for q=p`

Comment: I have edited the question,please check.

Comment: I think you mean to use `if rand < q` not `if rand < p`. The latter will be true if `rand` is smaller than all values in `p`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Rp is your matrix, then simply do one of the following:

If your matrix only contains zeros and ones

```
sum(Rp(:))
```

Or if your matrix contains multiple values:

```
sum(Rp(:)==1)
```

Note that for two dimensional matrices `sum(Rp(:))` is the same as `sum(sum(Rp))`

---

I think your real question is how to save this result, you can do this by assigning it to an indexed varable, for example:

```
S(count) = sum(Rp(:));
```

This will require you to add a count variable that increases with one every step of the loop. It will be good practice (and efficient) to initialize your variable properly before the loop:

```
S = zeros(length(p),1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix contains only `0` and `1` you are trying to count the nonzero values and there is a function for that called [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html)

```
n = nnz(Rp);
```

As I mentioned in the comments you should replace

```
if(rand < p)
```

with

```
if(rand < q)
```

Then you can add the number of nonzero values to a vector like

```
r = [];
for q=p(1:length(p))
    Rp=C;
    for i=1:N
        if(rand < p)
            Rp(i,:) = 0;
        end
    end
    r = [r nnz(Rp)];
end
```

Then `r` will contain your desired result. There are many ways to improve your code as mentioned in other answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count the 1's in any matrix `M` you should be able to do `sum(M(:)==1)`

Comment: This will count the number of `1`s per column, not in the entire matrix

Comment: Yes i know but i need to sum all the 1's together.Like Rp=[1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0] then my Rp=2.I cannot do this.

Comment: ehm... `sum(sum(M==1))`

Comment: @Nick-if i use your code then it sum up all the 1's from every Rp.But i need to sum the 1's for each Rp individually.